# How to apply a function to iterative rows of each pandas groupby object without using a for loop? (or a faster method than for loop)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a function

```py
def net_sale(df):
    if df['target'] == -1:
        return float(df['quantity1'] + df['quantity2'])
```

A `groupby` object

```py
g = df.sort_values(['date'], ascending=True).groupby('groups-concatenated-string')
```

I would like to apply transformation `"net_sale"` to each group in `g` without using for loop.

The following code is my solution: It works on a smaller dataset (50rows) but takes an infinite amount of time (est years) to run on a dataframe of 800k+ rows.

```py
for name, group in g:
    df['result_column'] = df.apply(net_sale, axis=1)
```

I am looking for a way to run this function "net_sale" to individual groups rows without having to use a for loop to iterate through the rows.

Sample dataframe:

```
    group   date    target   quant1   quant2   result_column
0    1      2018      0       10        NaN.      NaN
1    1      2018     -1        2        -2        0
2    2      2019     -1        3        -3        0
3    2      2019     -1        3        -1        2
4    2      2019      0       10        -1        9
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which includes a sample dataframe and your expected output.

Comment: A few performance suggestions: 1) Any solution that involves running a function on every row in your dataframe will be slow. apply() is a little faster, but it's still a for loop under the hood. 2) Since you're doing a row-by-row operation, you don't need to do a groupby. The operation will be the same without groups and with groups. 3) `.groupby('groups-concatenated-string')` Worth noting that you can [group by multiple columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups), which is faster than concatenating columns.

Comment: Your current solution doesn't make sense. You are iterating over the groups `g`, but not doing anything with `g`. You are just repeatedly applying the function `net_sale` to each individual row of the whole DataFrame `df`.  `net_sale` doesn't seem to depend on the group, so why do you want to apply to each group separately? Even assuming that `net_sale` is applied to each group `g`, the `if` condition wouldn't work because  `g['target'] == -1` produces a boolean mask, not a single boolean.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the expected output. Currently `df['result_column']` is just given by `df['result_column'] = df['quant1'] + df['quant2']`, regardless of the `target` column.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach calls the `apply` method for every row in your loop, so the run time is probably at least quadratic to the number of rows since each time `apply` is called it iterates over the entire DataFrame. You could try something like this:

```
def net_sale(row):
    if row['target'] == -1:
        return float(row['quantity1'] + row['quantity2'])
    # do you want to return null if row['target'] != -1? otherwise you should define an else case

df["result_column"] = df.apply(net_sale, axis=1)
```

If you provide a more detailed example of how your data looks and what the required output should look like there probably are faster approaches.

Comment: The lambda is unnecessary, `df.apply(net_sale, axis=1)` should be sufficient.

Comment: `row['quantity1'] + row['quantity2']` can probably be vectorized

Comment: @ddejohn You're right, i'll edit it. Started with a lambda method that used the two row values and handed them to the method as two parameters and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Isn't this what my current method is, though?

Comment: Yes but your loop calls this whole procedure for each group. You use `for name, group in g:` but then you don't seem to use `name` or `group` within that loop, see @Rodalms comment. You just do the entire, group-independent interation for (number of groups) times. I think what you want to do is doing the row iteration just once and handle the `groupby` logic afterwards. I don't think I fully understood what the `groupby` part of your code does/is supposed to do yet though.